# Linker not able to find functions in other static libraries

Tags: c, gcc, linker, gnu-make, ld

I'm trying to compile `fbi` (Linux framebuffer imageviewer) statically, so I added `-static` to `LDFLAGS` in `GNUMakefile`. Without `-static` linking works perfectly. When enabled, I get various linking errors telling me this:

`/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.a(fcxml.o): In function 'FcConfigMessage':
(.text+0x192): undefined reference to 'XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'`

Now I do have the static library `libfontconfig.a` and the function `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber` it obviously doesn't find is in `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxml2.a` which I proofed with `nm libxml2.a`, according to the source code found [here](https://github.com/servo/libfontconfig/blob/master/src/fcxml.c).

I guess I have to tell the linker in the `GNUMakefile` exactly what to do, but how? The object code in the `ar` libraries are all ARM 32-bit and I'm compiling and linking on ARM 32-bit.

GNUMakefile can be found [here](https://www.kraxel.org/cgit/fbida/tree/GNUmakefile), I added `LDFLAGS += -static --verbose -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpng12 -ltiff`.

Comment: note your library *order* might be important. Without a full link line we can't help you.

Comment: @tofro You're absolutely right, I added the information.

Comment: When you do `nm libxml2.a` does it show `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber` as a function defined there?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, but `xmlSAX2GetLineNumber` to which `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber` is defined to [here](https://github.com/servo/libfontconfig/blob/master/src/fcxml.c#L37).

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF Oh, the linker misses `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber`. Whereas `libxml2.a` provides `xmlSAX2GetLineNumber`. That is not going to link unless both function have the same name. Either `libfontconfig.a` should use `xmlSAX2GetLineNumber` or `libxml2.a` must define `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber`.

Comment: Okay, so this is a special case. I do get a bunch of other errors though, e.g. `libtiff.a` telling me that `lzma_stream_decoder` is undefined, whereas `lzma_stream_decoder` is definitely in `liblzma.a`: `00000494 T lzma_stream_decoder`. Could there be an order issue moreover?

Comment: _whereas `lzma_stream_decoder` is definitely in `liblzma.a`_ - but nowhere do you link it.

Comment: I do, I added `-llzma`.

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF As far as readers of your question are concerned, you do not. You are commenting on something we do not see.

Comment: Correct, that's because I have a lot more errors than the mentioned, to be precise [here](https://pastebin.com/q1N5eg5m) is the list of errors, can't put them to the question obviously. I will give it up, apparently it's not doable in reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

When one builds a shared library it often links other shared libraries it needs.

Whereas static libraries cannot link other libraries, so that when linking to that static library its dependencies must also be linked explicitly.

In other words, you cannot just sprinkle in `-static` and expect it to still link.

Try linking in that `libxml2.a` and other missing libraries until it links:

```
LDFLAGS += -static --verbose -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpng12 -ltiff -lxml2
```

Comment: I tried adding `-lxml2` as you suggested, but unfortunately it still tells me `libfontconfig.a` cannot find the functions in `libxml2.a`. Will try different order of `LDFLAGS`.